# Remove AM PM from input time drop down HTML

Tags: html, css, angular, input

[image: Image of my form]

I want to remove the AM / PM field in this drop down for input time format, if possible.

The form builder value is 24 hours based on this AM / PM field.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=angular+remove+am+pm+timepicker+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Also please post what picker you are using

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>      
    <script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var d = new Date();
        var h = d.getHours();
        var m = d.getMinutes();
        var s = d.getSeconds();
        document.getElementById("myTime").value = h+":"+m+":"+s;
        };
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="time" id="myTime" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It does not seem that this code answers the question that was asked. The question asked was aimed at hiding/removing a separate DOM Element for selecting AM/PM input. The code you shared will parse a time value in an input field and return it as ```HH:mm:ss```. This would only be part of a solution since the AM/PM element would still be visible.

Comment: As per the question, he wants to remove the AM / PM field in this drop-down for input, in 24hr format. So with code, the input displays 24hr. Please check with Run code snipet.

Answer (score 0):

try this : `input[type=time]::-webkit-datetime-edit-ampm-field { display: none; }`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.